# Is this a valid use for OneToMany JPA or am I misunderstanding this concept?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a SpringBoot API that has 2 domain JPA entities. One of these entities is 'Player' which stores information about the player of the game and includes their 'id' which is autogenerated and autoincrementing.

The 'Game' entity stores information about previous games that have been played, and has an autogenerated and autoincremeneting id also 'gameId'.

However I also want to store all of the 'Players' 'id' who participated in that game within the 'Game' entity.

Therefore, when a Game object is created, it will require the 'id' of 2 seperate Player entities.

Would a OneToMany relationship work in this case? Where the Player is annotated with @OneToMany above the 'id' field, and the Game is annotated with @ManyToOne above the 'playerId' field?

Kind of like this:

```java
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long gameId;
    
    @ManyToOne()
    private Long playerId;
    //Should this be multiple different fields like below?
    @ManyToOne()
    private Long player1Id;
    @ManyToOne()
    private Long player2Id;
    @ManyToOne()
    private Long player3Id;
    @ManyToOne()
    private Long player4Id;

}

public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @OneToMany()
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one from `baeldung.com`](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)

Comment: I would say that Player <-> Game is ManyToMany

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yeah that makes more sense, this is why when I tried to implement it I realized each Player could only have 1 game, thanks!

Comment: You're missing the **Object** part of [Hibernate ORM](https://hibernate.org/orm/) ! Like @Turing85 said, you should definitely start with the basics. If you don't like baeldung.com, [Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) has excellent tutorials too.

Comment: *"However I also want to store all of the 'Players' 'id' who participated in that game within the 'Game' entity.*" ... in relational databases, you don't think of "storing data within something" as much as "the relationships between your data."  In fact, it is entirely normal to establish relationships in an RDBMS without "storing" anything from one data set into the other (i.e. using bridge or junction tables).

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?
This make you able to get id of player who joined.

```
@Entity
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long gameId;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

    public Game(Long gameId, List<Player> players){
      ...
    }
}

@Entity
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
}
```

But I also recommend you reading a tutorial on this topic.
This could be easy way to solve, but unidirectional one-to-many mapping might not be a best practice. It should be used carefully.

`https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/`

For that reason I recommend you to use many-to-one relation instead of one-to-many like bellow.

```
@Entity
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long gameId;
}

@Entity
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    @ManyToOne
    private Game joinedGame;
}
```

Or if player can be joined in multiple games, consider middle-entity to loosen many-to-many relation, like Game - JoinPlayers - Player.